# Не отображается IP-адрес в событиях

Tags: windows, windows-server, rdp

В событиях Windows Server 2008 R2 при подборе пароля к RDP (событие 4625) не отображается IP-адрес, с которого была произведена попытка. И так во всех случаях. Из-за этого не срабатывает RDP Defender. В чём может быть проблема?

[image: Событие 4625]

Comment: Эти предложения форума [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/683837/) рассматривали?

Answer (score 0):

Нашли решение?
С января несколько серверов внезапно брутить начали. 2008й страдает - подключение по RDP подключается не с первого раза.
Нашёл варианты, что надо блокировать NTLM , но при этом надо проверять не заблокируются ли сетевые шары.
Пока по удалёнке не рискую..

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Это просто обычная проблема, что в 2008 IP не отображается. В более старших обычно всё нормально.. Хочу со временем от 2008 избавиться уже, но времени нет и железо надо менять.. старое глючит уже.